# Find matches between multiple CSV files

Tags: csv, awk

I have an indeterminated number of csv files in one folder. All the CSV have only one column with diferent number of rows, like this:

File1.csv

```
rs1000
rs2000
rs4000
rs5000
...
```

I want to compare all the CSV files in that folder and output a CSV file with only the rows that are in common in all the files. 
I have this command:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' *.csv > out_p.csv
```

but it shows rows that are not in all the files.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so we can test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test, but it should work.

```
awk '{line[$0]++}END{for(x in line)if(line[x]==ARGC-1)print x} *.csv
```

- The one-liner reads all lines into a hashtable (awk array)
- Increments the value(occurrence) each time
- Finally print out the lines with occurrence same as the count of `*.csv` files.
- **Note, assume that each csv file has no duplicated lines**

Comment: What does ARGC-1 do?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
awk '{ array[$1]++ } END { for(i in array) { if(array[i] > 1) print i } }' *.txt
```

Each csv file has only one column so you don't need to specify a field separator, a line is printed if it exists more than once in all the csv files.

Comment: It continues showing rows taht are not in common in all the files

Comment: @BorjaLeón Ah, so a row must be in ALL files.  In that case count the number of files and replace that number with the 1 now used in the if statement.